# Google maps v3 api, center map based on location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to center my map based on the location of the visitor, but somehow it doesn't work.

I have a PHP variable containing the country code of my visitor, which works fine when i check the source code in my browser. It looks like this;

```
<head>
...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var lang = <?php echo $lang; ?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
...
```

My script.js contains these lines;

```
function initialize() {

if (lang == NL) {
    var centerlat = 52.150892;
    var centerlng = 5.534668;
    var zoomlvl = 7;
}
else {
    var centerlat = 52.367896;
    var centerlng = 5.219407;
    var zoomlvl = 13;
}

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(centerlat,centerlng);
var myOptions = {
    zoom: zoomlvl,
    center: myLatlng,
    ...
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("kaart"), myOptions);
```

When i load the page containing the map it just doesnt appear. In the source code i can see the PHP variable displaying correctly.

Firebug says lang is undefined. Any idea whats going on here?

//edit: I have another variable done in the same way which works fine. But its outside the initialize function.

**Solved: Forgot quotes ^^**

Comment: So the map doesn't load and it says "lang undefined"? Is there anything else happening? Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Try surround NL with "".

As an aside have you looked into HTML 5 geolocation? Its relatively simple to implement and will give you a much more accurate location.

Take a look here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation and here:http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)
Yes ive looked into it, but since i dont want to center the map around my visitor, but around their country, and because all countries have different sizes (and different zoomlevels to display them correctly) i figured this way would work better. Please correct me if im wrong

Comment: Fair enough, just making sure that you were aware of the options :)

Answer (score 0):

> > Any idea whats going on here?

sorry, I don't have the rep to 'comment'

Is NL a string variable or a value (should it be "NL" ?)